# How to uninstall extension that was installed through .vsix

Tags: visual-studio-code

I [installed an extension from a VSIX](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix) but now I don't know how to uninstall it.

Comment: You uninstall it [just like any other extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_uninstall-an-extension)... Or did you have difficulty when you tried that? Please [edit] to clarify.